# Can I Perform Image Processing on Java Server with JJIL

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I have used JJIL library for processing images on Android phone.

Now I would like to apply the same functionality on a java server.

Can I use the JJIL library also on the Java server (compilation using eclipse or netbeans) to perform the same type of image processing (addition, convolution, transform to black and white, pure red, etc..)? I prefer to avoid rewriting the code from scratch but do not know if that is feasible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me which are the filters are available for images in jjil? I want to work it on android.

Comment: Also I have a problem converting Bitmap from RgbImage.

Comment: Bitmap.createBitmap(RgbImage.getData(), RgbImage.getWidth(), RgbImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));   
This is how u create a bitmap image from an RgbImage type

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I will try it, n let you know what happen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the home page of the project the answer is yes

> JJIL is particularly targeted towards mobile applications. It includes interfaces so images can be converted to and from native formats for J2ME, Android, and **J2SE**

J2SE means Java standard edition, and therefore the library doesnt seem limited to J2ME/Android (mobile)

http://code.google.com/p/jjil/